# Global location search in mapbox doesn't working on android

Tags: java, android, search, location, mapbox

I'm stuck on a problem with mapbox. 
The search place doesn't work. 
I have tried many things but nothing works.
When i click on the search button, nothing happen, and when i'm searching a place(by tipping in the search bar), nothing happen too, there is no suggestion

**The xml:file**

```
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.plugins.places.autocomplete.ui.SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_form_text"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:gravity="bottom|left"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_location_search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default" />
```

**PlacePluginActivity file :**

```
public class PlacesPluginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE = 1;
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapboxMap mapboxMap;
    private CarmenFeature home;
    private CarmenFeature work;
    private String geojsonSourceLayerId = "geojsonSourceLayerId";
    private String symbolIconId = "symbolIconId";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Mapbox access token is configured here. This needs to be called either in your application
        // object or in the same activity which contains the mapview.
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, Token);

        // This contains the MapView in XML and needs to be called after the access token is configured.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout_map_priere);

        mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    private void initSearchFab() {
        findViewById(R.id.fab_location_search).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder()
                    .accessToken("pk.eyJ1IjoibWVoZGluIiwiYSI6ImNrYTRobzR4YTB1MnAzbG9nMGljejBpb2UifQ.nG3vtoddC1TCHW3Skpkttg")
                        .placeOptions(PlaceOptions.builder().build())
                        .build(PlacesPluginActivity.this);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I don't know why it's not working, I can't find the problem here

Comment: what is not working exactly? what are you expecting and what do you get? is there an error or something else, bro we cannot divine what is the problem! and what did you try exactly? be clear.. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: When i click on the search button, nothing happen, and when i'm searching a place(by tipping in the search bar), nothing happen too, there is no suggestion.

Comment: please edit the question and mention that, otherwise it risks to be closed and you will not get answers

Answer (score 1):

Using the `SearchView` directly in your XML is probably the problem. The `SearchView` is used internally by the plugin.

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/testapp/activity/places shows your various options for setting up the plugin. Make sure to look at the XML layout file for each example activity https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/tree/83b191404b2d53da30f14fd7c671fe0b3eb9c4b6/app/src/main/res/layout (`activity_picker_launcher.xml`, activity_places_fragment.xml`, and`activity_places_launcher.xml`)

I'd clone the repo, add your token at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/testapp/PluginApplication.kt#L20, and then run the app on your device so that you can see what the examples look like.

Also, be careful about posting your Mapbox token on a public site. I'd rotate the token at https://account.mapbox.com/access-tokens/ so that others can't use your currently exposed one.

Comment: I don't understand the kotlin language. Thanks for the tips but i can't see how it's supposed to help me

Comment: Ok. Well https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/examples/global-location-search/ is in Java and shows how to use the plugin's launcher activity. The other option is to use a `PlaceAutocompleteFragment`
I converted https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/testapp/activity/places/AutocompleteFragmentActivity.kt into Java so that you can understand it:
https://gist.github.com/langsmith/661f7b7fbb897a77d3ca190144f31fc0